# Calling an operator over a series of members variables

Tags: c++, reflection, metaprogramming

I am looking for a method to call an operator over a series of member variables. My goal is to reduce the number of references to each variant to exactly 1. The following MWE illustrates what I have, and what I am trying to achieve.

Valid c++1z:

```
template<typename... Args> bool all(Args... args) { return (args && ...); }

struct foo {
  std::string m1;
  std::string m2;
  int m3;
  double m4;

  bool compare(const foo& rhs) const {
    return all(m1 == rhs.m1, m2 == rhs.m2, m3 == rhs.m3, m4 == rhs.m4);
  }
}
```

What I would like to achieve is something more of the form:

```
...
return all<*this, rhs>(m1, m2, m3, m4);
```

The exact syntax of the second form does not matter. However I am not looking for macro or "just write {return *this == rhs;} answers. There is no need to use modern features if they can be avoided.

Comment: Using `tup!e::tie` seems like a good way to go. If you can define a member  function that returns the elements to be compared as a tuple of references using `tie`, you get comparison between two such tuples for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass it pointer to members.

```
template <typename T_, typename... Ts_>
bool all(const T_* p1, const T_* p2, Ts_... ptrs)
{
    bool b []{ (p1->*ptrs == p2->*ptrs)... };
    for (int x = 0; x < sizeof...(Ts_); ++x)
    {
        if (!b[x])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

struct foo
{
    std::string m1;
    std::string m2;
    int m3;
    double m4;

    bool compare(const foo& rhs) const
    {
        return all(this, &rhs, &foo::m1, &foo::m2, &foo::m3, &foo::m4);
    }
};
```

A loop was what popped out of the top of my head, but I'm sure there is a better way to check all the comparisons.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. It didn't occur to me that you could expand a parameter pack like that. I ended up using std::all_of to test results.